# Java code size increases while using android app

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have developed a compose app which retrieves data from Socket each 3 seconds. While using app I recognized that after some time working with app it crashes with Out of memory. I profiled my app (release version) an saw that while using app java code increase until it crashes with OOM error. any ideas?

[image: AppProfiler]

Comment: Cannot help you, would need to see some code. Try this though: https://square.github.io/leakcanary

Comment: Here's how to profile: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler You'll have to do some detective work, and see what objects are building up in memory, and then find out why they're not being released!

Comment: Do you close sockets after use? Do you start new threads and if so, are you sure they finish and not just wait forever? You need to share some of your code.